# Swift - NSURLErrorDomain

Tags: swift

Всем привет! У меня при тестировании формы регистрации возникает вот такая ошибка:

> 2016-05-14 18:03:36.852 QaaP[25045:764432] App Transport Security has
>   blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure.
>   Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
>   error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource
>   could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires
>   the use of a secure connection."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f99f0724900 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.5/userRegister.php,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.5/userRegister.php,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.})

Код выглядит следующем образом:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.5/userRegister.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let posting = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)"
        request.HTTPBody = posting.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }


            do {
               let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                    print("result: \(resultValue)")

                    var userRegistered:Bool = false;
                    if(resultValue == "Success") { userRegistered = true }

                    var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!
                    if(!userRegistered)
                    {
                        messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Внимание", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Хорошо", style: .Default, handler: nil)

                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }


        }

        task.resume()
```

в чем проблема почему он не может получить данные , в plist может что добавить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в info.plist
App Transport Security Settings - > Allow Arbitrary Loads(YES) -> Exception Domains -> ваш домен(или ип адрес хоста)